# What is the difference between hashmap and Listmap in scala

Tags: scala, collections

Is there any difference between hashmap and listmap in terms of properties.

```
var listMap = ListMap("Rice"->"100","Wheat"->"50","Gram"->"500")    // Creating listmap with elements
```

and

```
var hashMap2 = HashMap("A"->"Apple","B"->"Ball","C"->"Cat")
```

Comment: mainly i am looking for advantage and disadvantage with each other

Comment: Anything that [the api scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html) doesn't tell you?

Answer (score 3):

Main difference: `ListMap` maintains the order of elements while `HashMap` doesn't.

In case of ListMap:

> Entries are stored internally in reversed insertion order, which means the newest key is at the head of the list. Iteration order is always guaranteed.

In case of HashMap:

> No guarantees on iteration order.

for more info:

ListMap
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html